# What are the names of wakeboard tricks that are performed at the corner of the cable?

Tags: terminology, wakeboarding, water-sports

If you jump right before the rope goes around the corner in a cable wakeboard park so you get cought by the twitch in mid-air, how do you call these tricks?

I found none in the [glossary](http://www.wakeboarder.com/tricks/glossary.phtml).

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Flyby"

Here is a nice video:
http://youtu.be/pfkOKwfPLF8

You need to sit on the bar to withstand the pull while you fly around the corner.

[Here a report of a german liftboy about this subject](http://www.wakeforum.de/viewtopic.php?p=163211#p163211)